# The space of test-functions carries any other structure on it?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I'm starting to study distributions and on the lecture notes I'm reading the author defines a test-function as a function $f : U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ which is infinitely differentiable and has compact support. He denotes the set of test-functions on $U$ by $\mathcal{D}(U)$.

It is obvious then that the set of test-functions carries a natural structure of a vector-space when we consider the usual pointwise addition and multiplication by scalar.

My question is: this space $\mathcal{D}(U)$ carries any other natural structure like that of a metric or normed vector space? Or for the purposes of distribution theory it is just always treated as a vector space without any topological or metric notions defined on it?

Comment: I think you can define a locally convex topology on $\mathcal D(U)$ which is induced by the family of seminorms $$\| f\|_{\alpha,K}:= \sup_{x \in K} |\partial^{\alpha} f(x)|$$ where $\alpha$ ranges over all multi-indices and $K$ ranges over all compact subsets of $U$. And a distribution is basically a continuous map from $\mathcal D(U) \to \Bbb R$ with respect to this topology. Maybe somebody can give a more reassuring answer though.

Comment: It's a normed vector space with the supremum norm $\| f\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in U} \lvert f(x) \rvert$. A problem is that it isn't complete with this norm but in some contexts there is a natural completion. For example, if $U = \mathbb R^n$, the completion is known as the Schwarz class which is important in Fourier analysis.

Comment: Complementing User8128's answer, $\mathcal D(U)$ cannot be given a "natural" norm http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673427/what-makes-a-norm-appropriate-why-cant-testfunctions-be-normed-appropriately.

Comment: @Shalop: While the seminorms that you state are important, the usual topology is not induced by these seminorms. Otherwise, it would not be true that if $f_n \to f$, then ${\rm{supp}} f_n \subset K$ for some fixed compact subset $K\subset U$ (independent of $n$).

Comment: It is also an algebra.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yeah you are correct. The topology you really want is the one in which $f_n \to f$ if and only if there exists some compact $K$ for which $supp f_n \subset K$ and $\|f_n - f\|_{\alpha,K} \to 0$ for all $\alpha$. This topology is not the same one as I defined in my previous comment, but it is still locally convex. Quite honestly I feel like this is a slightly subtle point, and it did take me a few minutes to think of a counterexample. Sorry about the mistake, and hopefully it didn't confuse the OP.

Comment: Hello. I have a doubt. What if we restrict ourselves to the case $U=K$ compact? Then, does what @shalop wrote hold?